# Can a python program configure logging before running the rest of code?

Tags: python, logging

**NOTE**: This question was based on an assumption that Python emits its error messages via logging. The answers show that the assumption is wrong.

---

I'm developing a program that is not started from a command line, but by a daemon. Stderr is redirected to null device.

Normally it logs messages to a file, but when some error is preventing a regular start, there is no error message to read, because it was sent to the null device.

To save a little debugging time in such case I tried a little "launcher" which adds a file handler to the root logger as the very first thing.

I have tested it with a deliberate syntax error in the `realprog` module. It logs the two "start" messages to the file, but the traceback from the syntax error is still printed to stderr. Could you please help?

```
import logging

logger = logging.getLogger()
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
logger.addHandler(logging.FileHandler('test.log'))
logger.info("logging start")

def real_start():
    # assume e.g. a syntax error in the realprog
    import realprog
    realprog.main()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    logger.info("program start")
    real_start()
```

Comment: can you post your error messages?

Comment: @HaifengZhang: `import realprog` fails with syntax error as expected. No other messages. Its a standard message with standard traceback. There is nothing wrong with the message itself except it gets printed, not logged to file. Do you need this error message?

Answer (score 1):

You could use:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    logger.info("program start")
    try:
        real_start()
    except Exception:
        # This will log the traceback.
        logger.exception("An error ocurred.")
```

However, you should increase your logger level to, at least, `logging.ERROR`.

Hope it helps!

Comment: I can confirm that it works and it helps. Thanks. But the message is explicitely logged. It seems like when Python complains about a syntax error, it bypasses the logging. Can anybody confirm this?

Comment: The `logging` module doesn't catch exceptions if that is what you're expecting.

Comment: I was expecting that the Python interpreter emits the error messages via logging.

Comment: But that's not the way `logging` works. You're responsible for logging whatever your want.

Comment: I see. I have added a note to the question that it's just (my) misunderstanding.

Answer (score 1):

You are not passing your exception to your logger, so there is no way for it to write it.

inside your `real_start()`, put your import statement and your function call in a try, catch and then log the exception.

Lets say for example your `realprog.main()` divides a number by zero, I want to log the exception, so I do this.

```
def real_start():
    try:
        import realprog
        realprog.main()
    except ZeroDivisionError as e:
        logger.info(e, exc_info=True)
```

If you check your file, you should have the exception inside it.

Comment: Yes, I'm not passing the exception to the logging system. But it gets printed anyway. That's why I have assumed Python interpreter does it.